# X11 does not forward everything

Tags: ssh, x11

I know there are many variations on this question, but I could not find a solution to this exact scenario.

Setting: local computer, remote computer (on the same local network).
On the local computer (Ubuntu 20.04), I have the following lines in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host remote
    User username
    HostName remote.local
    Port 223
    ForwardX11 yes
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

On the remote machine (Ubuntu 22.04) I have the following lines in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Port 223
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
```

(Of course, the port does not matter).
I connect via `ssh remote`, and that works with no issues. The `DISPLAY` variable is set (good) to `localhost:11.0` (perhaps sometimes to `localhost:10.0`). When I run `xclock` or `xlogo`, I see it fine. Works perfectly.

But here's the problem: whenever I run almost any other GUI app, it doesn't work. Sometimes, errors are printed, and sometimes, they fail quietly. Examples:

1. Running `eog picture.png` fails quietly. I don't see any message, nor the picture.
2. Running `evince`, I don't see the PDF, and I see repeating error messages: `gdk_monitor_get_scale_factor: assertion 'GDK_IS_MONITOR (monitor)' failed`. `gnome-calculator` fails with a similar error.
3. Running `firefox` fails (I don't see the browser, even when the process did not exist earlier), and I see repeating error messages: `X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.`
4. Running `firefox` a second time after disconnecting and reconnecting, the error message has changed: `Error: cannot open display: localhost:11.0`.

At this point, I'm a bit lost.

I also connected in a verbose mode, to look for interesting problems. The only potentially relevant lines I have found there are

```
debug1: Remote: /home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Remote: /home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: x11_get_proto: /usr/bin/xauth  list :0 2>/dev/null
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug2: channel 0: request x11-req confirm 1
```

Looks OK, doesn't it?

My use case is actually very simple: I need to plot graphs from within `sage` (or `Python`) remotely and see them locally. I was able to achieve this in the past with different computers, but that was a while ago. My workaround is to save the plots and open them locally (via `sshfs`), which is a bit silly.

Comment: Are you running X11 or Wayland (with XWayland) on you local computer? I would suggest you try to change that and see what happens.

Comment: I am running X11 locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are running Wayland remotely and the applications default to that.

Once you start the session you can do:

```
$ export GDK_BACKEND=x11
```

And normal (deb installed) applications will be forwarded. So you will be able to use `eog` and `evince` for example.

Firefox is most likely a snap in your configuration. There has been an issue with snaps for a very long time. This is one such bug at the snap bug tracker: ["X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication." when using snaps over ssh](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1602233). The last comment states that the bug is been triaged and there are workarounds, but the workarounds [no longer work](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/x11-forwarding-using-ssh/2381/25) (either exporting XAUTHORITY or linking .Xauthority to a place where the snap can see it).

Two alternatives for firefox:

- you could start the gdm sesion using X11 (logout, and at login, when you have to type the password there will be a cogwheel offering the type of session).
- download the firefox binary from firefox.com for your platform and run it instead of the snap. Since it is no longer a snap, it should work as `evince` and `eog`. It will also prompt you when there is a new version, to download it and update itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You are correct; it appears that I am running Wayland on the remote computer. I tried to SSH, run the export command you suggested, and then run `eog`, but it did not help (I mean, nothing happened). Running `evince` worked. Plotting from `sage` did not (main use case). I will try restarting the gdm session using X11 and report back.

Comment: That worked! This was indeed the issue. Thank you so much for your help!